# 16.04 and 17.04 Unity 8 black screen

Tags: drivers, unity, amd-graphics

I've been attempting to try out Unity 8 on both 16.04 and now 17.04 with no success.

As soon as i login, all I get is a black screen.  If I then get console up and login there and then try 'startx', then I get a background screen with an 'X' as cursor and that's it. Nothing else at all.
I'm fairly new to ubuntu so be gentle...
I suspect this is down to my graphics card & drivers ?

I am on a laptop with an AMD R7 M360 (Also with intel integrated) and have to use the default drivers.
When looking for amd-pro drivers it seems there are not any for my exact card model (http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux).
I've seen mentioned that open source drivers have problems with Unity 8/Mir and so am wondering if the lack of amd-pro drivers for my card could be causing this unity 8 failure for me ?

Anything else I can try ?

Thanks

EDIT:

If I run lspci -k  to see what comes up, I get 2 entries for my video:

```
0:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 520
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
And:01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445] (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

I'm confused as to which graphics card/system is being used by ubuntu. Ideally I'd like to just be using the AMD one, so is there a way of disabling one ? I could try disabling one or the other and see if Unity 8 works with either the Intel or AMD card only ?

Comment: It's not open source drivers that are a problem generally, but proprietary ones. Unity 8 does not use X11. Are you certain of which GPU and driveres are being used? I don't think hybrid video is supported well with amdgpu drivers yet.